# Урезанный комбобокс

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать комбобокс, который, пока по нему не щелкнули, внешне представляет собой только маленькую стрелочку (не знаю, как точнее назвать) без поля для ввода. Но когда по нему щелкаешь, значения показываются целиком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сократите его ширину до размеров стрелочки(20px вроде) также обработайте событие выбора, и измените размер на нужный...

открыл таки делфу...

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
ComboBox1.Width:=100;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ComboBox1 do
if Text='' then Width:=20;
end;
```

Comment: Блин система меня зарегистрировала заного))

Answer (score 0):

Сделать 2 комбобокса 1ый - кастрированный, а второй ценный. Написать условие, что изначально первый `show` а второй `hide`. По клику меняем у них значения местами?

Comment: Зачем второй комбо не понимаю, больше гемороя с синхронизацией

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы сам комбобокс всегда оставался "стрелочкой"?

Comment: На вскидку только 2мя компонентами) или модификацией отрисовки бокса.